pandasql not working properly with postgresql python
I have this Postgres SQL function:
_df = sqldf("""select
 id,
 version,
 c_num,
 mode() within group (order by duration_sec) as mode_duration_secs,
 .9*mode() within group (order by duration_sec) as mode_dur_secs_lb 
from tmp_jr
group by id,version,c_num;
""")

ERROR: OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
When i remove:
    mode() within group (order by duration_sec) as mode_duration_secs,
     .9*mode() within group (order by duration_sec) as 

The code works without errors.
Here is my tmp_jr table:



id
duration_sec
c_num




a1
116
20


a1
279
3


a2
9
19


a3
16
16


a3
17
19



Don't know what am doing wrong here.
